# What is the maximum amount of iterations in this loop in order to avoid crash?

Tags: c++

What is the maximum number of iterations in this case when n decreases by one everytime and the number is huge

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std; 
int main() {
unsigned long long n = 1000000000000000000;
while(n)
n--;
}
```

Comment: Why do you say that there is a crash to avoid?

Answer (score 3):

The C++ standard does not specify a maximum for loops that don't do anything (no input or output etc. etc.). The *as-if* rule for compilation permits the compiler to optimise the result to

```
unsigned long long n = 0;
```

So the maximum will be zero for any sensible compiler with appropriate compilation optimisations set.

Reference: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if

---

In your case, a compiler with optimisations set will reduce your *entire program* to

```
int main(){
    return 0;
}
```

(Note that the `main` has an implicit `return 0;` on any control path if not given by the programmer.)

Comment: when does it occur specifically?

Comment: @FabioDiLieto: During compilation.

Answer (score 2):

The maximum number of iterations will be the size of `n` if it's reduced by 1 in every iteration. If it is reduced by 2 then it will be iterate `n/2` times it depends on how you're reducing the size of `n` at run time.

Answer (score 2):

There is no "iteration limit" in C++. Furthermore, your loop is likely completely removed. Here's what GCC [generates](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/cfPvqh):

```
main:
        xor     eax, eax
        ret
```

As you can see, no looping is done at all. It simply returns zero.

Comment: Well done for writing out the code! Have an upvote! (For those who don't read assembly, xor a register to itself is quicker than setting it explicitly to zero.)

Comment: when are loop removed?

Comment: The compiler removes it because it knows it has no effect.

Comment: @FabioDiLieto There is something called the "as if" rule, which means the compiler is allowed to change your code as much as it likes as long as you can't detect it. Here, your program essentially has no observable behavior, so the compiler does nothing (except for returning zero.)

Answer (score -1):

There is no any limitation on iteration for loops. For example your loop can be infinite.

But there is limitation with stack size, so cannot create infinite recursion. Loops don't create any new stack frame.

Most of GUI application are working in the infinite loops.

Comment: Not entirely true: the compiler can optimise out recursion too.

Comment: How is it performed that optimisation?

Comment: Optimising compilers are written by very very smart people!

Comment: @Bathsheba Compiler can unroll your loop, but cannot transform it to recursion. Cause short jump is simple operation, and compiler will not replace short jump from loop to long/far jump from function call.

Comment: @SimMak: Indeed - but I was saying that a compiler can optimise out recursion too (e.g. tail recursion -> loop).

Comment: @Bathsheba Yep, recursion can be transformed to loop, but loop cannot be transformed to recursion.

Comment: why could be occur?